# HashCode Behavior in HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

My Employee Class :-

```
class Employee {

    String name;
    int age;

    public Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) obj;
        return employee.getAge() == this.getAge()
                && employee.getName() == this.getName();
    }

    // commented    
     @Override
        public int hashCode() {
                return (int) Math.random();
        }

}
```

Utilization :-

```
        Employee employee = new Employee("rajeev", 24);
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("rajeev", 25);
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("rajeev", 24);

        HashSet<Employee> employeesList = new HashSet<Employee>();
        employeesList.add(employee );
        System.out.println(employeesList.contains(employee2));
        System.out.println("employee.hashCode():  " + employee.hashCode()
        + "  employee2.hashCode():" + employee2.hashCode());
```

I will get the **True**. But i should get the false?
Because employee and employee2 are in differenct buckets and having different HashCode.
Sample Output:-

```
true employee.hashCode():  0  employee2.hashCode():0
```

What is the wrong with the code ?
All i want is different `hashcode` (different bucket) and correct implementation of `equals` method which returns `employeesList.contains(employee2)` false.

Comment: They have the same `hashcode` because `Math.random()` returns a positive `double` value smaller than `1.0` , which will always yield `0` when cast to an `int` .

Comment: Read the javadoc of hashCode(). And don't use `==` to compare strings. The hashCode value should always return the same value for a given value of name and age. Use `Objects.hash(name, age)`. Always returning 0 as you're doing will make your HashSet inefficient. Always returning a random value will make it non-working because that doesn't respect the contract of hashCode.

Comment: Different hashcode doesn't necessarily mean different bucket.

Comment: Generating a random hashcode breaks the required contract and will cause your HashSet to fail completely.  You will not be able to find objects in the set.  You must write a `hashCode()` method that uses the same fields which define equality (name and age).

Answer (score 3):

For what you want, you can just remove the `hashCode()` method from your `Employee` class. The default implementation will return different values for different objects (but it only looks at object identity, so even two objects with the same values in their fields will have different `hashCode`s if you don't override the method)

Note: it's not 100% guaranteed that they're different - actually it's not defined how exactly the identity hash code is created - but they will be different in practice.

The reason that your current code fails is that `Math.random()` returns a value from 0 up to 1 (but never 1). If you cast that to `(int)`, the result is always zero.